# Разные view для списка

Tags: java, android, recyclerview, kotlin

Решил сделать в списке групировку по датам, что то подобное такому:

```
27 february      
   item1      
   item2   
26 february     
   item1
```

Возникла проблема в составлении условия по которому дата должна быть добалена в список. Код `getItemViewType`:

```
var previousDate = ""
override fun getItemViewType(position: Int): Int {
    val currentDate = batteryStories[position].date.toFormatDate(DATE_FORMAT)
    if(currentDate != previousDate){
       previousDate = currentDate
       return HEADER_VIEW_INDEX
    }
     return BODY_VIEW_INDEX
 }
```

Данное пробное решение работает только при первичной прогрузке списка и прокрутка проводит к хаосу. В результате нескольких прокруток выходит нечто такое (дата выводиться при первом появлении уникальной даты в списке):

```
   item1      
   item2   
27 february     
   item1
26 february
```

Даже при удачном результате мне кажется сравнение строк это не лучший вариант. Как лучше реализовать подобное?

Comment: Передавайте вашему адаптеру уже готовый список. А сгруппируйте его в другом месте. К примеру это может быть презентер или утильный метод

Comment: @ВиталийРобиновский, список не может содержать обьекты разных типов, в примерах я все упростил, для примера item это обьект класса Battery.

Comment: Почему не может? Используйте несколько ViewHolder. В интернете найдете  несколько вариантов как можно реализовать.

Comment: @ВиталийРобиновский, спасибо, реализовал через обобщённый список.

Answer (score 0):

Что бы не было хаоса при прокрутке, нужно в `onBindViewHolder()` обязательно добавлять вначале явное указание состояния вьюхи (например: `myViewHolder.tvDate.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE))`, а дальше уже ставить ей видимость при необходимости. Дело в том что контейнеры в RecyclerView переиспользуются и мы получаем такую вот интересную ситуацию.